# Setting columnWidth and rowHeight in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, gridbaglayout

How to set columnWidth and rowHeight in GridBagLayout? Is it gridWidth and gridHeight?

[image]

How this column Widths can be specified dyanmically?

Comment: How do you mean "dynamically"

Comment: After a button click event some textfields and labels are added.  Its Ok, currently i am looking into jgoodies formlayout.  It seems, its very flexible and very nice.

Comment: jgoodies is extremely flexible

Answer (score 4):

According to the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html)

gridheight

> Specifies the number of cells in a column for the component's display
>   area. Use REMAINDER to specify that the component's display area will
>   be from gridy to the last cell in the column. Use RELATIVE to specify
>   that the component's display area will be from gridy to the next to
>   the last one in its column.
>
> gridheight should be a non-negative value and the default value is 1.

gridwidth

> Specifies the number of cells in a row for the component's display
>   area. Use REMAINDER to specify that the component's display area will
>   be from gridx to the last cell in the row. Use RELATIVE to specify
>   that the component's display area will be from gridx to the next to
>   the last one in its row.
>
> gridwidth should be non-negative and the default value is 1.

So, if you want to specify the number of rows or columns a component will span, then, yes

Comment: Seriously, you have to love blind down votes. Please, feel free to leave a comment as to why you feel this answer doesn't fulfil the requirements of the question and or possible ways it might be improved.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot specify the `width` and `height` of a cell in GridBagLayout; if that is what you are looking to do. Th layout manager calculates row height  based on all components in the row.

You can check this [Oracle tutorial on GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

**Added**
Based on the screen shot you added seems you are using some tool like JFormDesigner. It is a customised layout, column width and column height does not come in standard GridBagLayout.

Comment: What is the tool you are using?